# selecting a set of rows with specific record data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I here today with a question that has left me rather confused and puzzled. Perhaps someone out there could give me a bit of assistance.

I have three table as followed. Please note that they are simplified for this question.

//table_checks//

```
check_id |task_id| status
   1     |  1    | Done
   2     |  1    | Done
   3     |  1    | Done
   4     |  2    | Done
   5     |  2    | Not Done
   6     |  2    | Not Done
   7     |  2    | Not Done
   8     |  2    | Done
   9     |  3    | Done
  10     |  3    | Done
  11     |  3    | Not Done
  12     |  3    | Done
```

//table_user//

```
user_id |  email   | type
   1    |  a@a.com | IN
   2    |  b@b.com | IN
   3    |  c@c.com | EX
```

//table_chk_usr//

```
check_id |user_id 
   1     |  1    
   2     |  1    
   3     |  1    
   4     |  2    
   5     |  2     
   6     |  2     
   7     |  2     
   8     |  2     
   9     |  3     
  10     |  3     
  11     |  3     
  12     |  3
```

Here are three tables with its relation in the table_chk_usr table.

My question is how do I query and select rows of `table_user` with type `'IN'` from table `table_user` where all of users assigned `task_ids` in the `table_checks` are with the `status` = `done`.

So the expected result should be as follows

//table_user//

```
user_id |  email   | type
   1    |  a@a.com | IN
```

Since user_id with 1 has completed all task_ids with status done.

I hope this makes sense to those of you who are reading. Any help will be much appreciated.

Please Note that I am using PHP as my server side language, if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
select user.user_id, user.email, user.type, 
sum(if(status = 'done',1, 0)) as done, count(*) as checks
  from checks
   join chk_user on checks.check_id = chk_user.check_id
   join user on chk_user.user_id = user.user_id
   group by chk_user.user_id
   having done = checks
```

[sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b6a/13)

Comment: ..wow I'm speechless. If you ever need a kidney or liver transplant send me a msg.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join here, but there may be a better way to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM table_checks
INNER JOIN table_chk_usr
  ON table_checks.check_id = table_chk_usr.check_id 
INNER JOIN table_user
  ON table_chk_usr.user_id = table_user.user_id
WHERE table_checks.status = 'Done'
AND table_user.type = 'IN'
```

Comment: (1) 2nd JOIN is missing table name. (2) You are not checking that **all** tasks assigned for a user have status "Done".

Comment: You also forgot about "type='IN'" but this is trivial

Comment: Did not mean to confuse you. I was merely pointing out that you forgot about OP's requirement to return only users **with type 'IN'**.